# how to retrieve record from list with caml by passing title/column value query in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, custom-list

I want to retrieve a record from SharePoint list by passing field value to CAML query using javascript,I tried below code

```
function retrieveDetails(name) {

    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);//Get the SharePoint Context      object based upon the URL
    var myList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("PersonalDetails");
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    query.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><eq><FieldRef Name=\'Name\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>' + name + '</Value><FieldRef Name=\'email\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'></Value></eq>" + "</Where></Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>');
    var items = myList.getItems(query);
    ctx.load(items);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        Roomdetailstable(items);
    }
    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
            '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
}
function details(items) {
            var itemInfo = '';       
            var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();       
            while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
            var currentListItem = enumerator.get_current();     
            var rnmae = currentListItem.get_item('Name');
            document.getElementById("rnme").innerHTML = rnmae ;
            var emailid= currentListItem.get_item('email');
            document.getElementById("emailid").innerHTML = emailid;

        }
    }
```

but it is showing error like below
[image]

Comment: Have you tested your caml query with something like the u2u caml query builder: http://www.u2u.be/Software ?

Comment: your query seems to be wrong. You are using two fields in the query but there is no And/Or operator in your query. As suggested by @MartijnE, use CAML query builder to build the query

Answer (score 2):

resolved this issue by removing `<Query></Query>` from my caml query

```
function retrieveDetails(name) {

    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);//Get the SharePoint Context      object based upon the URL
    var myList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("PersonalDetails");
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    query.set_viewXml('<View><Where><eq><FieldRef Name=\'Name\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>' + name + '</Value><FieldRef Name=\'email\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'></Value></eq>" + "</Where><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>');
    var items = myList.getItems(query);
    ctx.load(items);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        Roomdetailstable(items);
    }
    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
            '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
}
function details(items) {
            var itemInfo = '';       
            var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();       
            while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
            var currentListItem = enumerator.get_current();     
            var rnmae = currentListItem.get_item('Name');
            document.getElementById("rnme").innerHTML = rnmae ;
            var emailid= currentListItem.get_item('email');
            document.getElementById("emailid").innerHTML = emailid;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your caml query is wrong. If you want to be sure it's not the code, please try this caml query:

```
query.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name=\'ID\' /></IsNotNull></Where></Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to get the data from SharePoint list using CAML query.

```
function retrieveDetails(name) {

    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);//Get the SharePoint Context      object based upon the URL
    var myList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("PersonalDetails");
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    query.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><eq><FieldRef Name=\'Name\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>' + name + '</Value><FieldRef Name=\'email\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'></Value></eq>" + "</Where></Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>');
    var items = myList.getItems(query);
    ctx.load(items);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );


}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
        var itemInfo = '';       
            var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();       
            while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
            var currentListItem = enumerator.get_current();     
            var rnmae = currentListItem.get_item('Name');
            document.getElementById("rnme").innerHTML = rnmae ;
            var emailid= currentListItem.get_item('email');
            document.getElementById("emailid").innerHTML = emailid;
    }
    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
            '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
```